# Awaitility not working JAVA+APPIUM+CUCUMBER

Tags: java, cucumber, awaitility

I am currently facing a weird issue using java awaitility library.
I am using awaitility to wait for a minute and check one condition using the below statement.

```
 String currentTime = getAvailableDriveTime();
await("Wait for time")
    .atMost(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .until(this::getDriveTime, not(currentTime));
```

```
 public String getDriveTime() {
        String driveTime = appiumDriver.getPageSource();
        driveTime = driveTime.split("CurrentTimeString\":\"")[1];
        return  driveTime.split("\",\"ArcColor\"")[0];
    }
```

The weird part is, the above statement works fine with a sample Appium Test script, but the same does not work with a cucumber+Appium+ java framework and throws the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)
    at org.awaitility.core.AbstractHamcrestCondition.getMismatchMessage(AbstractHamcrestCondition.java:76)
    at org.awaitility.core.AbstractHamcrestCondition.access$300(AbstractHamcrestCondition.java:25)
    at org.awaitility.core.AbstractHamcrestCondition$1.eval(AbstractHamcrestCondition.java:55)
    at org.awaitility.core.ConditionAwaiter$ConditionPoller.call(ConditionAwaiter.java:190)
    at org.awaitility.core.ConditionAwaiter$ConditionPoller.call(ConditionAwaiter.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at ✽.Driving time in the driving overview screen will be updated(file:src/main/resources/EFSFeatureFiles/HOS&DVIR/VehicleMotionFeature/EFSVehicleMotion_DriverLoggedIn.feature:83)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include the code for `getDriveTime`?

Comment: I have added the code for getDriveTime. Thank You

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your question as well?

Comment: I have added the stack trace. Thank you